# Add team with auth user

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

i'm trying to add team with auth user i have route with middleware('auth')
But i can't get auth user. I'm new in node.js so i think its really easy problem but really can't see how can i solve this problem...

```
public async store({ request, auth, response }: HttpContextContract) {
        const user = auth.user
        const validations = await schema.create({
            name: schema.string({}),
            size: schema.string({}),
        })
        const data = await request.validate({ schema: validations })
        const team = await Team.create(data)
        console.log(Object.keys(team));
        return response.created(team)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that the user is **authenticated** to use the auth.user object.
**add this**

> await auth.use('web').authenticate()

```
public async store({ request, auth, response }: HttpContextContract) {
            await auth.use('web').authenticate()
            const user = auth.user
            const validations = await schema.create({
                name: schema.string({}),
                size: schema.string({}),
            })
            const data = await request.validate({ schema: validations })
            const team = await Team.create(data)
            console.log(Object.keys(team));
            return response.created(team)
        }
```